# How can I get the text of EditText control when I use customize BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I use the following  `ListNumberAdapter` to fill in a `ListView` control. I hope to get the text of all `EditText` control in the `ListNumberAdapter`, how can I do? Thanks!

BTW, I think I shoud add some code in the function `public Object getItem(int arg0)`... but I don't know how to do.

```
    private void IniListView(){
        ListView lv=this.getListView(); 
        mListNumberAdapter=new ListNumberAdapter(this,mList);
        lv.setAdapter(mListNumberAdapter);      
    }



public class ListNumberAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<String> mListNumber;
    private Context mContext;

    public ListNumberAdapter(Context context, List<String> listNumber){
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       
        mListNumber=listNumber;
        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mListNumber.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_list_phone_number, null);
            holder.tvContactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
            holder.editNumber = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editnumber);
            holder.btnAddress=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddress);
            holder.btnDelete=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.id=position;
        holder.tvContactName.setId(position);
        holder.editNumber.setId(position);
        holder.btnAddress.setId(position);
        holder.btnDelete.setId(position);

        String s=mListNumber.get(position);
        String name=HandleSMS.GetUserNameByTelNumber(s);
        holder.tvContactName.setText(name);
        holder.editNumber.setText(mListNumber.get(position));        

        holder.btnAddress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                  Button btnAddress=(Button)v;
                  PublicPar.telNumberIndex=btnAddress.getId();                
                  ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(i, 50); 
            }
        });           

        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button btnDelete=(Button)v;
                mListNumber.remove(btnDelete.getId());
                notifyDataSetChanged();  
            }
        });         

        return convertView;
    }
}




class ViewHolder {
    int id;
    TextView tvContactName;
    EditText editNumber;
    Button btnAddress;
    Button btnDelete;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when you need to obtain data from views inside a ListView (or a GridView), it is not quite as simple as iterating over these views, and accessing their properties: for example, checked state of a CheckBox, selected option in a RadioGroup, and in your case, user's input in an EditText. The reason why this isn't simple: ListViews serve Views on demand.

Say you have a ListView which has 20 items to show. Given a certain screen size, it can probably display 8 items, and you need to scroll to access the rest. If at this point, you try to access all 20 Views, you will most certainly run into a `NPE`: because all 20 Views simply don't exist. On scroll, older views (those that are not on screen anymore) are recycled and/or new views are created.

> I think I shoud add some code in the function public Object
>   getItem(int arg0)... but I don't know how to do

This method's purpose is to serve data to the BaseAdapter. Its *mostly* used in the getView(...) method to return an Object using the `position` argument. Method's body, in your case, will look like this:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return mListNumber.get(arg0);
}
```

Its usage:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        ....
    } else {
        ....
    }

    String currentItem = (String) getItem(position);

    // use 'currentItem'
}
```

**Solution:**

Maintain data yourself.

Create an `ArrayList<String>` inside your BaseAdapter:

```
public class ListNumberAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<String> mListNumber;
    private Context mContext;

    // List
    private ArrayList<String> mListData;

    public ListNumberAdapter(Context context, List<String> listNumber){
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                      context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       
        mListNumber=listNumber;
        mContext=context;

        // Create and initialize the list
        mListData = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mListNumber.size(); i++) {
            mListData.add("");
        }
    }

    ....

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            ....
        } else {
            ....
        }

        ....

        // Update 'mListData' whenever EditText's content changes
        holder.editNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                   int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
                   int before, int count) {}

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // Text has changed
                mListData.set(position, s.toString())
            }
        }); 

        return convertView;
    }

    // Use this method to obtain 'mListData'
    public ArrayList<String> getCurrentEditTextContent() {
        return mListData; 
    }
}
```

So, from your activity, you would obtain the data using:

```
ArrayList<String> currentContent = yourAdapter.getCurrentEditTextContent();
```

By the way, you will also have to change `holder.btnDelete's` OnClickListener: when you remove an object from `mListNumber`, do the same operation for `mListData` to maintain consistency.

Answer (score 2):

set unique id or tag for the editText in getView

like:
     holder.editNumber.setTag("editNumber"+position)

you can get all values of editText by iterarting

```
public List<String> getNumbers(){

    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
        EditText number = (EditText)listView.findViewWithTag("editNumber"+i)
        numbers.add(number.getText().toString());
    }
    return numbers;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, why for(int i=0;i<listView.getCount();i++)  cause error.

Comment: its not listView.getCount(), its listView.getAdapter().getCount()

Comment: Thanks! Can I add some code in the function public Object getItem(int arg0) to do it ?

Comment: yes, you can. Usually all i do in it is return data corresponding to the row

Answer (score 0):

Create one hashmap in your adapter like :

```
private HashMap<EditText, String> values = new HashMap<EditText, String>();
```

Add one line to your getView Method of Adapter before returning the convert view

```
....
values.put(holder.editNumber, holder.editNumber.getText().toString());
return convertView;
....
```

Create a new Method to get the values you require :

```
public Collection<String> getCurrentlyShownValues(){
        return values.values();
    }
```

You are done....